# SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) in Gruntfile

Tags: gruntjs

I am getting an error when trying to run my Gruntfile to resize images. I followed the tutorial but am not sure how to add my additional task.
The error is

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) in Gruntfile

The line is :

> ```
> });
> ```

From what I can tell it looks as though that ) is needed.

```
// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({
  pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
  uglify: {
    options: {
      banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n'
    },
    build: {
      src: 'src/<%= pkg.name %>.js',
      dest: 'build/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js'
    }
  },
  resize_crop: {
    image_group: {
      options: {
        format: "jpg",
        gravity: "center",
        height: 30,
        width: 30
      },
      files: {
        '/Users/john/changeimages/30x30': [
          '/Users/john/changeimages/stopsign.jpeg'
        ],
      },
    }
 }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-resize-crop');
```

Comment: Apart from the extraneous commas, I cannot see an obvious problem. However, given how grunt works, there should be a surrounding function. You should include all of your code in your question.

Comment: I included my entire Gruntfile.js

Answer (score 2):

Try getting rid of the two extra commas after the end of the array in the `files` object, and after the `files` object itself:

Change this:

```
files: {
  '/Users/john/changeimages/30x30': [
    '/Users/john/changeimages/stopsign.jpeg'
  ],
},
```

To this:

```
files: {
  '/Users/john/changeimages/30x30': [
    '/Users/john/changeimages/stopsign.jpeg'
  ]
}
```

Comment: Good catch. That probably wasn't needed but I'm still getting that same error even after removing it.

Comment: Did you remove both commas?

Comment: I removed the second one now, but I am still getting the same error unfortunately.